# Use if-else to evaluate the starting number and the length of a number in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I am a beginner of C.

I try to use if-else to evaluate if a number starts with 4 and has certain digit. It is fine when I test it with `card_num = 4000000000000000`, but I have no clue why it goes to else when I test with other numbers that start with 4 and have same length, such as `card_num = 4003600000000014`. These two numbers are supposed to have same result.

Please help me! Thanks!

```
    int main(void)
    {
    
        long card_num;
        card_num = 4003600000000014;
    
        if ( (card_num / 1e12 == 4 || card_num / 1e15 == 4) )
        {
            printf("Valid\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid\n");
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `char card_num[] = "4003600000000014";` which is a string containing digits? The first digit is `card_num[0] - '0'`. Don't be led up the wrong path by the word 'number'. My house 'number' is 212b but it isn't a (decimal) number.

Comment: Chapter 1 in the average C programming book typically addresses numerical limits of integer types,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1e15` is a `double` constant, so using it in an expression results in floating-point arithmetic being used. When `card_num` is 4003600000000014, the result of `card_num / 1e15` is approximately 4.003600000000014 (approximate because of floating-point), so `card_num / 1e15 == 4` is of course false, causing program control to flow to the `else`.

You could solve the instant issue by using `floor(card_num / 1e15) == 4`, but that is not a good idea. Do not use floating-point arithmetic for manipulating integers (at least until you learn thoroughly about floating-point arithmetic and have good reason for this).

You could also solve the instant issue by using `card_num / 1000000000000000 == 4`, but that is not a great idea. Avoid using numeric types for manipulating credit card identifiers. Credit card “numbers” are actually strings of digits; they are not intended to represent numbers. E.g., credit card 4003600000000014 is not the four-quadrillionth-and-some card issued, the “4” is a code for the issuer. Aside from the digits not being intended to represent numbers, there are so many of them that they cause problems with the standard C numeric types.

Preferably, you should read the credit card “number” as a string (and then check that the user entered only digits, and an acceptable number of digits, for it). If you must read it as a number, convert it to a string (perhaps with `sprintf`, or `snprintf` if you want to practice writing safe code) immediately after reading it and work with it as a string.

Comment: Thanks! Your solutions work! But why it shows 4 when I print ```card_num / 1e15``` ?

Comment: @P.H.: How do you print it?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value for a `long` <del>is</del> may be, depending on your architecture, 2,147,483,647, and 4,003,600,000,000,014 is way more than that.

(Credit) card numbers aren't something you do math on, so store it as a string and do those operations on the string instead.

Comment: *The maximum value for a long is 2,147,483,647*  [Not always true](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1): "Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or **greater** in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign."  `long` is 64 bots on almost every non-Windows 64-bit platform.  `LONG_MAX` on such systems would be 9223372036854775807.

Comment: Fixed to a "may be", fine. But the point still stands; this is really a number string, not a number. :)

Comment: The wired thing is, the result is correct when I test with ````4000000000000000````. And I'm going to do some more math calculation on the number, that's why I prefer to use ```int``` or ```long```

Comment: @P.H. Do you really mean calculations on the credit card number or do you mean single digits of the card number? The latter can be done even better when using a string.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your long into string using sprintf:

```
char bigbuff[12];
long num = 4003600;
sprintf(bigbuff, "%ld", num);
```

Now bigbuff[0] contains the first digit (as character) and strlen(num) gives the length of your initial number.

Comment: Could get a bit tricky to print a 16 digits number into that array...

Answer (score 0):

Using `long` built-in datatype with values not exist on [−2,147,483,647, +2,147,483,647] range causes an overflow, so you have to use `long long` datatype to wide your range to [−9,223,372,036,854,775,807, +9,223,372,036,854,775,807] range.

You can also use the `unsigned` keyword before the datatype to shift the range to positive values only (e.g. `unsigned long long`'s range is [0, +18,446,744,073,709,551,615] ).

Comment: I tried to use ```long long``` but still got the same result.

Comment: *Using long built-in datatype with values not exist on [−2,147,483,647, +2,147,483,647] range*  That's not true.  `long` is 64-bit on just about every 64-bit platform with Windows being the only notable exception.

Answer (score 0):

As you are a beginner, let me give you some tips: you say that you are working on a collection of digits, meaning a cardnumber, and you want to do some calculation on that. What type will you use for that?

In case you are doing mathematical calculations, then using a number type (like `int` or `long`) might be a good idea.
In case you might be using "text-alike" functionalities, then it might be useful working with a string or an array of characters.

*What do you mean by "text-alike" functionalities?*
Well, imagine you want to do something with a certain digit (like the third one). You might get that digit using the following calculation:

```
(cardnumber / 1E13) MOD 10
```

Why 1E13? Because I imagine your number being 15 digits long, and division by 1E13 is what you need to find the third digit.

Wouldn't it be far more easy to do this:

```
cardnumber[3]
```

In other words, just access the third digit.

Luckily, in your case, you only need the first digit, so the integer division by 1E15 gives you what you need.

So, choosing a number type is ok for this particular case.

Then, there's the thing about which number type: as you mention your cardnumber have a size of about 1E15, while the maximum `long` number seems to be about 2E9, so this is not a good type for this. It seems, however, that `long long`, with a maximum of about 9E18, is more suited for this.

As far as the second part of your if-condition, the division by 1E12: as your number has a length of 15 digits (the first one never being zero, I guess), this condition is useless.

Comment: Your analysis is correct!!! I want to check the length and the first number of a number entered by user, and will do more math calculation on it. I tried ```long long``` but still got the same result.

Comment: @P.H. You mention that the (final) result is the same, but what about intermediate results? Did you check your program, using a debugger? Did you show the value of the cardnumber in the debugger? And what about `card_num / 1E15`? Did you remove the other condition? ... I'm afraid you'll need to do some debugging in order to understand what's going wrong.